# How dynamically give datepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to dynamically giving date format using jquery ui.But it doesn't work. My code is

```
 <table id="sample">
<tr>
    <td>
        Date
    </td>
</tr>
```

js:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
 $("#sample tr td").after('<td><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>');
```

fiddle:
      http://jsfiddle.net/gtwswufu/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First append the input and then initialize the plugin:

```
$("#sample tr td").after('<td><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>').queue(function() {
   $('#datepicker').datepicker();
   $(this).dequeue();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't intialize the plugins like that, the plugins has to be initialized once the target dom elements are created. So in your case

```
var $td = $('<td><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>').insertAfter('#sample tr td');
$td.find("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2uemtLsf/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Date
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="date" id="datepicker"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/mrd9fpun/